# missing glyphs on web pages

Tags: browser, fonts

I have a rooted Galaxy Note Pro.

I'm annoyed at black blocks that appear instead of whatever symbol, when reading web pages.  I copied Code2000, Symbola, and the BMP Fallback ttf files to /system/fonts, but (e.g. https://en.m.wikiversity.org/wiki/Reed%E2%80%93Solomon_codes_for_coders#Finite_field_arithmetic ) I still see a block instead of the symbols for Real and Integer domains.  This [test page](http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/letterlike_symbols.html) shows lots of blocks in Firefox. The Android browser simply skipps them instead. I also tried Opera.

Is there something needed to register ttf files, other than copying them to the directory? ( Total Commander remounts the file system r/w ) and rebooting?

It's annoying that I can display Tamil, Myanmar-extended-A, and other things I can't actually read, but am missing symbols and marks that appear in pages I *do* wish to read.

Answer (score 2):

Android keeps track of fallback fonts via a file at `/etc/fallback_fonts.xml`. After adding your fonts to `/system/fonts`, you can add a new `family` node to the XML file like this.

```
<familyset>
    <family>
        <fileset>
            <file>Custom-Font.ttf</file>
            <file>Another-Custom-Font.ttf</file>
        </fileset>
    </family>
[rest of file...]
```

Make sure to make a backup first, and you might need to reboot for it to take effect completely.

Comment: Very interesting!  I see there is also a file `fallback_fonts_sbrowser.xml` but the comments in it are just the same. What's that for?

Comment: @JDługosz I don't know what that file is for. My phone doesn't have it. Maybe it's some sort of extra customization or testing done by your phone's manufacturer or carrier? The comments at the start of my phone's `*_fonts.xml` files both refer to an optional `/vendor/etc/fallback_fonts.xml` file, but that's it.

Comment: FWIW, I’ve still never gotten it to work.